# Maximum possible length of FileVersionInfo.FileVersion string on Windows

Tags: c#, file, io

I want to store version in database table and don't want to use `varchar(max)` for that. I want something fixed `varchar(xxx)`

Could you please tell, what's the maximum possible length of `FileVersionInfo.FileVersion` on Windows Platforms?

Actually figured out how to get proper version:

```
var ver = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("D:\\oraociei11.dll").FileVersion;
```

This returns for Oracle lib:

```
OraOCIEI11.dll - 11.2.0.1.0 Production
oracore11.dll - 11.2.0.1.0 Production
oranls11.dll - 11.1.0.6.0 Production
orasnls11.dll - 11.1.0.6.0 Production
oraunls11.dll - 11.1.0.6.0 Production
oravsn11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oracommon11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orageneric11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oraclient11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orapls11.dll - 11.1.0.6.0 Production
orasql11.dll - 11.1.0.6.0 Production
oraxml11.dll - 11.1.0.6.0 Production
orahasgen11.dll - 11.2.0.1.0 Production
oraocrutl11.dll - 11.2.0.1.0 Production
oraocr11.dll - 11.2.0.1.0 Production
oraocrb11.dll - 11.2.0.1.0 Production
oranbeq11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orantcp11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orantcps11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orannmp11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orancds11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranldap11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oraldapclnt11.dll - 10.1.4.0.1 Production
oraolapapi11.dll - 
oranhost11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orantns11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranoname11.dll - 
oransgr11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orancrypt11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oransgr11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranl11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranro11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranbeq11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orantcps11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orannmp11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orancds11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranldap11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oraldapclnt11.dll - 10.1.4.0.1 Production
orannzsbb11.dll - 11.0.0.1.0 Production
oran11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
orannzmcs11.dll - 11.0.0.1.0 Production
oranjssl11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranjni11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
oranipc11.dll - 11.2.0.2.0 Production
```

To get version of file in proper way:

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("D:\\oraociei11.dll");
var properVersion = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", versionInfo.FileMajorPart, versionInfo.FileMinorPart, versionInfo.FileBuildPart, versionInfo.FilePrivatePart);
```

Thanks guys for participating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, FileVersion is a string and can contain anything.  The Visual Studio resource editor allows entering a string of up to 300 characters.  That is however not enforced by the resource compiler, longer strings can be entered by editing the .rc file by hand.

What you'll want to do is synthesize the version string yourself, like this:

```
        var info = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);
        var version = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", 
            info.FileMajorPart, info.FileMinorPart, info.FileBuildPart, info.FilePrivatePart);
```

Which then ensures this string can never be larger than 23 characters.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion.aspx) it is a 64 bit number, split into 4 pieces of 16 bit each.

This should mean that each section can be up to 65535, so the total formatted string could be 65535.65535.65535.65535, giving a total length of 23 characters.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion.aspx) says it's composed of 4x16-bit numbers. So I would say 5 (max for a short is 65535) * 4 + 3 dots, so a maximum size of `23` characters.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I added comment upper.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion.aspx), the FileVersion is a formatted string built from a 64 bit integer. This integer is the concatenation of 4 16 bit integers accessible via FileMajorPart, FileMinorPart, FileBuildPart and FilePrivatePart. As such you have two options, given that 2^16-1 = 32767.

One option would be to construct and store the underlying 64 bit integer in an appropriate column and re-parse this when the data is loaded. This is guaranteed to work as it is the documented form.

If you can assume the canonical form of the FileVersion (which is not guaranteed by the framework as the documentation says that this is merely the typical form) then the maximum length should be 23 (4 5 digit numbers separated by periods).